# desmalezar vs desbrozar vs escardar

Tags: sinónimos

Is there any difference in meaning and usage between "desmalezar", "desbrozar" and "escardar" (= to weed) ? I cannot see a clear difference in meaning by reading their definitions in DLE (https://dle.rae.es/desmalezar , https://dle.rae.es/desbrozar , https://dle.rae.es/escardar) and in Word Reference.

Regarding usage, according to Word Reference and DLE, "desmalezar" is an americanism. What about the other two?

Comment: Are we talking about weeding (removing weeds)?  If so, what I have heard in the countryside in Mexico is *limpiar* or *quitarla maleza*.  I don't know about other countries.

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, that's the meaning.

Comment: I've never heard *campesinos* in Mexico use any of these terms.  I don't know about other countries, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the three verbs have a similar meaning: to remove unwanted vegetal mass:

- Desmalezar means *quitar la maleza*.
- Desbrozar means *quitar la broza*.
- Escardar means *quitar los cardos o malas hierbas*.

So the difference is what you are removing:

- Maleza (malas hierbas) means weed. So you are removing still alive plants.
- Broza means *dead leaves, dead brushwood o trash*. So you are removing dead branches, leaves or plants.
- Cardo is a *thistle*.